# Xerces Version Conflicts in Java

Tags: java, maven, xerces

I am working on a project that requires Xerces 2.11.0, which is included in my project as a Maven dependency. However there is also a version of Xerces included in my JRE (Version 2.7.1). I am getting the below exception when running my code. I believe (according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1868724/java-lang-classcastexception-org-apache-xerces-parsers-xincludeawareparserconfi)) that I'm having trouble because of the multiple versions of Xerces. I've read the thread on [Xerces Hell in Java/Maven](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11677572/dealing-with-xerces-hell-in-java-maven) however it doesn't seem to address the issue where the other version of Xerces is coming from the JRE itself. Any advice?

```
Exception Trace:
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/w3c/dom/ElementTraversal
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:760)
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:467)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:368)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:362)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:361)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.newDocument(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xalan.transformer.TransformerIdentityImpl.createResultContentHandler(TransformerIdentityImpl.java:230)
        at org.apache.xalan.transformer.TransformerIdentityImpl.setDocumentLocator(TransformerIdentityImpl.java:881)
        at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.DomLoader$State.<init>(DomLoader.java:67)
        at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.DomLoader.startElement(DomLoader.java:103)
        at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.ProxyLoader.startElement(ProxyLoader.java:45)
        at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext._startElement(UnmarshallingContext.java:559)
        at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext.startElement(UnmarshallingContext.java:538)
        at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.InterningXmlVisitor.startElement(InterningXmlVisitor.java:60)
        at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.StAXStreamConnector.handleStartElement(StAXStreamConnector.java:231)
        at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.StAXStreamConnector.bridge(StAXStreamConnector.java:165)
        at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal0(UnmarshallerImpl.java:400)
        at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(UnmarshallerImpl.java:371)
        at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.message.stream.StreamMessage.readPayloadAsJAXB(StreamMessage.java:313)
        at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.api.message.MessageWrapper.readPayloadAsJAXB(MessageWrapper.java:171)
        at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.fault.SOAPFaultBuilder.create(SOAPFaultBuilder.java:540)
        at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.StubHandler.readResponse(StubHandler.java:237)
        at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.db.DatabindingImpl.deserializeResponse(DatabindingImpl.java:189)
        at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.db.DatabindingImpl.deserializeResponse(DatabindingImpl.java:276)
        at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(SyncMethodHandler.java:104)
        at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(SyncMethodHandler.java:77)
        at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SEIStub.invoke(SEIStub.java:147)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy54.processVoid(Unknown Source)
        at com.shipping.ups.UPSShippingProvider.voidShipment(UPSShippingProvider.java:378)

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.w3c.dom.ElementTraversal
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        ... 75 more
```

** EDIT Maven Shade

```
       <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.3</version>
            <configuration>
              <filters>
                <filter>
                    <artifact>xerces:xercesImpl</artifact>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>META-INF/services/**</exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </filter>
              </filters>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
              <execution>
                <phase>package</phase>
                <goals>
                  <goal>shade</goal>
                </goals>
              </execution>
            </executions>
          </plugin>
    </plugins>
```

Comment: Do you have xml-apis 1.4.01 among your dependencies?

Comment: I do. xml-apis 1.4.01 is being pulled in along with xml-apis-ext 1.3.04

Comment: Looks like something is searching for `org.w3c.com.ElementTraversal` in the wrong classloader. Does your app work if you remove (via maven-shade-plugin) the `META-INF/services` directory from `xercesImpl jar`? That's how it registers as a SAX implementation.